# R: Create Variable and Display Value in Single Command

Tags: r

Is there a way to both create a variable and output its value in a single command? In other words, concatenating both lines below into a single command?

```
x <- mean(1:7)
x
```

Comment: Wrap in parantheses `(x<- mean(1:7))`

Comment: or just dart your eyes over to the Environment pane in RStudio

Comment: @Hack-R - This is for an R Notebook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the command in parantheses.

```
(x <- mean(1:7))
```

Knowing this you can do a few cool R tricks like creating an object and using it in the same expression. The development team does this all over the R source code. This is a double nest from `apply`:

```
if (length(dn.call) && !is.null(n1 <- names(dn <- dn.call[1])) && 
        nzchar(n1) && length(ans.names) == length(dn[[1]]))
```

Be careful with these newfound powers, your co-workers will never be able to read your code again :)